# Increment a date by a number of days, months or years

Tags: excel, date, vba

I have a date which I will need to increment the date by a day, month or year from the actual date. This is based of a list of fields below and is different per the input. Also each resultant date has to be a business day i.e not a weekend day or a bank holiday. I will forgo the Bank Holiday requirement now.

I am using the formula `=DATE(YEAR($A$1),MONTH($A$1),DAY($A$1))` and hard coding the increment value in each row based of the value in B4 below.
Also once we get past SP in column A4 the formula changes to reference the date created by using the value at the SP value.

So if we put the results in to column E the formula will change to `=DATE(YEAR($E$6),MONTH($E$6),DAY($E$6))`
The date also needs to be in the format `text(xx,"mm/dd/yyyy")`

Any suggestions on how to create this in Excel of VIA a VBA solution macro would be appreciated

```
A1
=today()

A4 B4
ON  1 Day
TN  2 Day
SP  2 Day
SN  2 Day
1W  7 Day
2W  14 Day
3W  21 Day
1M  1 Month
2M  2 Month
3M  3 Month
4M  4 Month
5M  5 Month
6M  6 Month
7M  7 Month
8M  8 Month
9M  9 Month
10M 10 Month
11M 11 Month
1Y  1 Year
15M 15 Month
18M 18 Month
21M 21 Month
2Y  2 Year
3Y  3 Year
4Y  4 Year
5Y  5 Year
6Y  6 Year
7Y  7 Year
8Y  8 Year
9Y  9 Year
10Y 10 Year
15Y 15 Year
20Y 20 Year
25Y 25 Year
30Y 30 Year
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a user defined function, somthing like that

```
Function IncDate(ByVal dt As Date, ByVal add As Long, ByVal dmy As String) As Date

    Select Case UCase(dmy)
        Case "DAY"
            IncDate = DateAdd("d", add, dt)
        Case "MONTH"
                IncDate = DateAdd("m", add, dt)
        Case "YEAR"
                IncDate = DateAdd("yyyy", add, dt)
        Case Else
                IncDate = dt
    End Select
End Function
```

And then you could write in D

```
=IncDate(TODAY();B4;C4)
```

You then need to format the cell to your needs.

Result would look like that

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment - this does not seem to work - I have copied the function however the formula returns "#VALUE!" - is the syntax correct in the formula?

Comment: Also I dont have much experience with functions - one other question is that my hard coded data will go in to columns A-C. Should the formula using the function go in to D or E? The formula and screenshot you provided would lead me to think D however you mentioned E. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it should beD. The data will go into A to C and then you put the formula in D. The syntax is correct for a german version of excel, you probaly have to replace the ; with a , `=IncDate(TODAY(),B4,C4)`

Comment: Perfect that worked. Regards ensuring the date generated is a day between Monday - Friday so if the date resultant from the initial function is Sat or Sunday how do I move the date forward to the following Monday?

Comment: I think this a new request. Try something on your own and if you get stuck create a new post

Comment: Thanks I have created what I require in Excel and created a new post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639504/retutn-only-buisness-days-in-custom-date-function-in-excel