# Retutn only Buisness days in custom date function in excel

Tags: excel, function, date, vba

I have a date which I will need to increment the date by a day, month or year from the actual date. This is based of a list of fields below and is different per the input. Also each resultant date has to be a business day i.e not a weekend day or a bank holiday. Also if the resultant date is either Dec 25 or Jan 1st the day needs to move forward to the next business day (not a weekend day).

I have created this in Excel using a couple of formulas though it is a bit clunky.

Below is my data set

Business Date   15/05/2018

```
Tenor   Settlement Value    Settlement Period
ON  1   Day
TN  2   Day
SP  2   Day
SN  3   Day
1W  7   Day
2W  14  Day
3W  21  Day
1M  1   Month
2M  2   Month
3M  3   Month
```

In column E - I am using formula

```
=IF(D4="Day",$B$1+C4,IF(D4="Month",EDATE($B$1,C4),(TEXT($B$1,"dd/mm/")&(YEAR($B$1)+C4))+0))
```

In column F - I am using formula

```
=E4+LOOKUP(WEEKDAY(E4),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7},{1,0,0,0,0,0,2})
```

In column G - I am using formula

=F4+IF(AND(OR(TEXT(F4,"ddmm")="2512",TEXT(F4,"ddmm")="0101"),WEEKDAY(F4)>=2,WEEKDAY(F4)<=6),LOOKUP(WEEKDAY(F4),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7},{0,1,1,1,1,3,0}),LOOKUP(WEEKDAY(F4),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7},{1,0,0,0,0,0,2}))

In H I format the date in mm/dd/yyyy and I have my desired result.

storax has kindly created a function for me which replicates my excel formula in column E - on this thread [Increment a date by a number of days, months or years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50608032/increment-a-date-by-a-number-of-days-months-or-years)

```
Function IncDate(ByVal dt As Date, ByVal add As Long, ByVal dmy As String) As Date
    Select Case UCase(dmy)
        Case "DAY"
            IncDate = DateAdd("d", add, dt)
        Case "MONTH"
                IncDate = DateAdd("m", add, dt)
        Case "YEAR"
                IncDate = DateAdd("yyyy", add, dt)
        Case Else
                IncDate = dt
    End Select
```

Could use some advise on how I could incorporate my formulas in columns F & G to make the process less clunky.

Comment: research workday.intl and networkdays.intl at support.office.com.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating the DATE function (DateSerial in vba) with the [WORKDAY.INTL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/workday-intl-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d) seems to produce the correct business dates.

Put this in E4 and fill down.

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(YEAR(B$1)+(D4="year")*C4, MONTH(B$1)+(D4="month")*C4, DAY(B$1)+(D4="day")*C4)-1, 1, 1, holidays)
```

[holidays] is a named range (Formulas, Defined Names, Defined Name) with a Refers To: of,

```
=Sheet10!$Z$2:INDEX(Sheet10!$Z:$Z, MATCH(1E+99, Sheet10!$Z:$Z))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have copied your instructions however I return the value #VALUE!. Can you elaborate on this point - [holidays] is a named range (Formulas, Defined Names, Defined Name) with a Refers To: of, I have created a named range for holidays.

Comment: If you are returning #value! then there is something askew with your data, likely text where true numbers should be. If you created a holidays named range then you should be fine; I just showed how to make it dynamic.

Comment: Thank you for your help - my issue was that in my defined name range I included both the date and narrative on the date which caused the function to kick out. Once I renamed the range correctly it worked a treat - thanks again.